# Program that tests whether three numbers make up the sides of a right triangle

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the program I have so far:

```
def main4():
    if isRight():
        print('it is right')
    if not isRight():
        print('it is not right')
def isRight():
    n1=int(input('Enter first number:'))
    n2=int(input('Enter second number:'))
    n3=int(input('Enter third number:'))
    if n1<n2 and n1<n3:
        smallest=n1
    elif (n1<n2 and n1>n3) or (n1<n3 and n1>n2):
        smaller=n1
    elif n2<n1 and n2<n3:
        smallest=n2
    elif (n2<n1 and n2>n3) or (n2<n3 and n2>n1):
        smaller=n2
    elif n3<n2 and n3<n1:
        smallest=n3
    elif (n3<n2 and n3>n1) or (n3<n1 and n3>n2):
        smaller=n3
    elif n1>n2 and n1>n3:
        largest=n1
    elif n2>n1 and n2>n3:
        largest=n2
    else:
        largest=n3
    if largest**2==(smallest**2)+(smaller**2):
        return true
    else:
        return false
```

When I call the main function, it allows me to enter the three numbers but then returns this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    main4()
  File "/Users/L/Documents/maxoftwo.py", line 45, in main4
    if isRight():
  File "/Users/L/Documents/maxoftwo.py", line 71, in isRight
    if largest**2==(smallest**2)+(smaller**2):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'largest' referenced before assignment
```

I cannot figure out how to solve this error, and would appreciate it if someone helped me out. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're only assigning at most one of `largest`, `smallest`, and `smaller`.

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is structured to work is to go into just of one the 9 conditional blocks you have to compute the values for `smaller`, `smallest` and `largest`. When it comes out of one of these blocks, only one among the `smaller`, `smallest` and `largest` are declared. So when the code gets to the point to execute the statement

```
if largest**2==(smallest**2)+(smaller**2):
```

if only finds one of the those three variables and hence throws the error you are seeing. To fix that, you can declare all three variables after you take the user input with:

```
smallest=largest=smaller=0
```

after you ask the user to input the variables and you should get your program to work.

Some other issues with your code:

- `True` and 'False`are defined keywords in python,`true`and 'false`
  are not. So make sure you use the capitalized words for those.
- In the `main4` routine, the second `if` can be replaced with an
  `else`. In your current code, the function `isRight` will be invoked
  twice which is not necessary.
- You can simplify your conditions to calculate `smaller`, `smallest` and `largest` variables to:

  ```
  smallest = min(n1, n2, n3)
  largest = max(n1, n2, n3)
  smaller = list(set([n1, n2, n3]) - set([smallest, largest]))[0]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Before you use local variable `largest`, you have to assign a value.

```
def main4():
    result = isRight()

    if result:
        print('it is right')
    else:
        print('it is not right')

def isRight():
    largest = 0              # <-
    smallest = 0             # <-
    smaller = 0              # <-
    ...

    # calculate each other
    if largest**2==(smallest**2)+(smaller**2):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions *only set a single variable*. You need to split your long if/elif chain into 3 pieces, each of which sets one of `smallest`, `smaller`, and `largest`.